# Efficient dynamic import of multiple scripts in module type Web Worker

Tags: javascript, performance, web-worker, es6-modules, dynamic-import

I have a web app that needs to dynamically load multiple scripts on startup. For efficiency, it needs to request all the scripts over the network in parallel. For correctness the scripts must execute in a specific order.

In the DOM this can be achieved by dynamically adding `<script>` tags with the `async` property set to `false`. The requests go out in parallel, and the scripts run in the order the tags are added.

In a classic type Web Worker (the default), you can use `importScripts(...arr)`. The browser gets a list of all the scripts in one go, and so can request them all simultaneously, but guarantee the scripts run in the order specified.

In a module type Web Worker, things get trickier. `importScripts` is not allowed in a module type worker (Chrome throws *Module scripts don't support importScripts()* if you try). Workers can't add script tags. You can however use dynamic `import()` - but that only accepts one script. If you import scripts one at a time like this:

```js
async LoadScripts(scriptsArr)
{
    for (const src of scriptsArr)
        await import(src);
}
```

This serializes the network requests to run one after another, which is inefficient.

The only thing I can think of to do is dynamically create a module that consists solely of `import '...';` lines, and dynamically import that, like this:

```js
async LoadScripts(scriptsArr)
{
    // Create a string with a module full of import statements
    const moduleStr = scriptsArr.map(src => `import '${src}';`).join("\n");

    // Create a blob from the string
    const blob = new Blob([moduleStr], { type: "application/javascript" });

    // Dynamic import the blob, which in turn loads all the import statements
    await import(URL.createObjectURL(blob));
}
```

This feels like a pretty ugly hack though, like a glorified `eval()`. Is there a better way?

Comment: "*I have a web app that needs to dynamically load multiple scripts on startup*" - can you elaborate a bit on the requirements, please? Why is it dynamic, how is it decided which scripts need to load and which don't? What goes wrong if they load in an unexpected order?

Comment: We make Construct 3, a full game development IDE in the browser. The game preview works locally and is modular, potentially including locally-installed third-party addons. So there isn't a fixed list of scripts to load in preview, and the third-party scripts that depend on the runtime must come after the runtime scripts, and the runtime has its own internal dependencies too (as I mentioned in another comment, we're migrating from classic scripts so don't have an import dependency chain yet)

Comment: I think for a preview feature without server interaction, `createObjectURL` is a very good and appropriate solution. The actual build for the game would then probably generate this as a static file.

Answer (score 4):

> For correctness the scripts must execute in a specific order.

If the scripts do have dependencies, they should declare these explicitly with import statements.

Creating a single module that imports everything in the right order, like the one you are constructing dynamically, is also an option, probably the list of modules is pretty static actually.

> If you import scripts one at a time, it serializes the network requests to run one after another, which is inefficient.

If the modules have their dependencies declared, you can load them all at once:

```
function loadScripts(scriptsArr) {
    return Promise.all(scriptsArr.map(src => import(src));
}
```

Comment: We're migrating from classic scripts, so we're using the 'import for side-effects only' syntax, i.e. `import 'foo.js';`

Comment: @AshleysBrain But why, if you're not using the module features? And how do you deal with exports, put everything in the global scope?